# How to produce a JS editor/textarea that styles each *word* based on its length

Tags: javascript, html, editor, rich-text-editor, codemirror

I want to style each word *separatly* depending on its length and potentially on other properties (such as the length of the line it is sitting on).
This should happen in real time as the user types, and on the same textarea as he is typing.

I have been trying (with small success) to use wysiwyg editor js libraries such as CodeMirror, but i am thinking it could be overkill as the intendend content is simple text. However, I would be really happy to use one of those as they offer other interesting features (such as autosave) that I could surelly use in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery for this.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zqkyau03/1/) is a fiddle that switches the color of the input text based on its length (odd = blue, even = red).

```
$('.myInput').keyup(function(){
    var inLength=$(this).val().length;
    if (inLength % 2==0){
        $(this).css("color", "red"); 
    }
    else{
        $(this).css("color", "blue");
    }
})
```

Comment: This is changing the css for the whole text area, i would like to change each word _separatly_. I don't think it is possible using a single element!